# I'm confused on registers, stack pointer, and let a register point to stack pointer

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers, stack-pointer

Could someone help me with these problems? what is a stack pointer? does it have its own address? what does it mean to let a register point to a stack pointer?

here are some examples that I don't understand.

```
1.    STR R6, [R9, R8]
```

so this line is supposed to store the value of R6 to the address of R8 using R9 as the base pointer. I'm interpreting this as incrementing by R8 to the base pointer, store the value there. But I'm not sure why R8 is a valid incrementation.

```
2.    STR R1, [R0]
      MOV R0, #3
```

my teacher said this will not change the value stored in the address of R0[SP] after we assign R0 with 3. But I don't understand how is RO and SP related, and how is it working.

thank you!

Comment: That's ARM syntax, not MIPS.  But on both (and most others), the stack pointer is a register, and therefore nothing can point to it.  You can't take the address of a register, but you can use it's *value* as a pointer.  Usually with 2-register addressing modes, one is a pointer and the other is a small integer offset (usually an array index).

Comment: i don't understand what does it mean to use its value as a pointer, could you explain a bit more on this? and what does MOV R0, SP this mean?

Comment: A memory address is basically just an integer in assembly language.  Registers hold integers.  That's what we call the "register value".  So a register who's integer value is a valid memory address is "holding a pointer".  The "stack pointer" register is one who's value is the address of the current top-of-stack, e.g. of the last thing you pushed.  Using a register as part of the right hand side of a load or store instruction accesses memory using the address calculated from the register values. (according to the addressing mode selected by that asm instruction, e.g. `[r0]` simple register).

Comment: A register can hold either a value or an address.  A value is a typical numerical calculation.  Maybe a distance calculation, etc.  An address can also be treated as a value (perform calculations on it), but it has some underlying memory associated with it.  A *pointer* is a common term to describe an *address* in a register.  Some forms of pointer calculations make sense and other dont.  For instance 'pointer + value' is a way to get an element of a vector/array/matrix, etc.  'pointer - pointer' could be used to get a size.  'pointer + pointer' is usually nonsense.  [Rn] in arm is a pointer.

Comment: So in an instruction like `str r6, [r9,r8]`, it only makes sense if R9/R8 are  pointer/address and a value/offset (one of each).  The registers themselves are not in memory.  You must use a `str` to put a register value in memory.  The registers are a like a fast alternate piece of memory; a scratch pad where you can do calculation quickly.  They must be place back in memory (via address/pointer) to store them permanently.  The 'scratch pad' (registers) is a completely different copy from memory.

Answer (score 4):

> Could someone help me with these problems?

Here's some background:

In order to provide the capability for one function to call another (itself even, as in recursion), modern processors and operating systems work together to provide a thread or call stack to programs.

When one function calls another, it effectively suspends itself, transfers control of the processor (i.e. the executed instruction stream) to the new function and waits for it to return.  A suspended function is essentially interrupted, mid execution, by its calling of another.  Further, newly called functions are said to be activated, which means their local variables come into existence, and later leave as the function returns (deactivates).

The call stack facilitates suspension, activation, and resumption necessary as part of calling and returning.  The call stack is a logical data structure that involves 2 notable things:

- a memory area, which is called the stack, runtime stack, thread stack, or **call stack**,
- an indicator of how much of the stack is in-use vs. is free/available, called the **stack pointer**.

The stack pointer is a simple mutable global variable.  This global variable holds a single value that delineates in-use stack memory from available stack memory.  It also indicates where the next allocation can occur, as well as where in the stack memory the last allocation occurred — all of these are at one and the same boundary.

Functions that need some stack space for their internal purposes, such as to store local variables, temporary values, and parameters — especially while they are suspended calling another — can easily allocate space from this stack data structure by changing the stack pointer, which logically moves some memory from free to in-use or vice versa — without actually moving any physical memory or moving memory values.

At the start of a program, the stack pointer global variable logically refers to one extreme end of the stack memory area, indicating that the stack memory is all available, and correspondingly that none is in use.

For a stack that grows downward, merely decrementing the value of the stack pointer global variable logically transfers some of the free stack space (memory that already exists at least in address space) into the in-use stack space by the decrement amount — as far as the hardware is concerned, nothing necessarily happens to the physical memory.

By agreement of all software, the stack pointer global variable tracks the boundary between free and available call stack memory, and so all software honors that the memory referred to above the stack pointer is considered taken/in-use/claimed (and below is available/free).

As a genuine stack data structure (LIFO), allocated stack memory can only be released in reverse allocation order, e.g. by incrementing the stack pointer global variable.  It is critical that as a function exits to return to its caller, it restores the stack pointer to the value it was upon its entry — logically releasing any stack space it allocated, and so that the caller being returned to finds its own variables that it place onto the stack earlier.

In mapping the call stack data structure onto physical hardware, the stack data structure's memory is mapped simply to an area of your address space — a chunk, an array of bytes, reserved for the call stack data structure.  And the stack pointer global variable is so important that it is usually mapped to a dedicated CPU register, in ARM's case, the `sp` register.

---

> what is a stack pointer?

Logically speaking, it is a global, mutable variable that is used dynamically (and by software agreement) to indicate the boundary between available memory of the call stack, and in-use memory.  This logical variable has a mapping to a physical CPU resource, the `sp` register.

> does it have its own address?

No, generally it is too important of a variable to be stored in slow memory, so it usually gets its own dedicated CPU register.  The stack pointer global variable is also a simple scalar value, so easily stored in any CPU register that is of pointer size.

As only memory has addresses, the registers, including `sp`, do not have addresses.

There is no requirement to point to the stack pointer variable — what's needed often is its value, the value held in that variable, i.e. to point to some variables that have been mapped to the stack.

On the other hand, the stack memory itself needs to be addressed/addressable/pointed to, in usage, so as is consistent in general with memory, every byte in the stack memory area has unique memory address.

> what does it mean to let a register point to a stack pointer?

This is misworded.  The stack pointer global variable, as a logical element of the call stack data structure, maps to the physical resource of a CPU register, namely `sp`.

The stack pointer variable, located in the `sp` register, holds the unsigned integer value or binary bit pattern corresponding to the memory address at the boundary between in-use and available stack memory.  When we allocate stack space, the `sp` points to (holds the numeric value of the address of) the newly allocated stack space (and because the stack grows downward, the `sp` points to the beginning or lowest address of newly allocated space).

A function that allocates stack space doesn't know at compile time where that stack space will be, but it knows at compile time where it's stack-based variables will be relative to the `sp` register (whose value isn't know until dynamic activation of the function).  Once the function is activated it can compute the absolute address of its local stack-based variable (by adding the value held in `sp` to compile time constants).

In this way recursive functions can be activated multiple times (on the call stack multiple times), and each have their own independent local variables.

---

(Some compiled code or assembly code also uses the concept of a frame pointer, which can complicate the explanation of the stack, but suffice it to say that while the stack pointer refers to the lowest address of newly allocated stack space, the frame pointer refers to the other end of a function's newly allocated stack space.)

Answer (score 0):

> STR{cond} Rd, addressing_mode

> The STR (Store Register) instruction stores a word from register  to the memory address calculated by addressing_mode.

> Syntax [Rn, +/-Rm]

> This addressing mode calculates an address by adding or subtracting the value of the index register Rm to or from the value of the base register Rn.

Bits is bits, addresses are bits, data is bits, its just bits it does not mean anything except to us.

A stack is just memory that we use as a quick way to allocate and free memory without a need for a system call.  A stack pointer is a "pointer" it is an address that points at the stack.  But nothing in your question is related to the stack.

```
STR R6, [R9, R8]
```

So this takes the bits in R8 and R9 and adds them together then it uses that as an address.  Then it stores the bits from R6 into memory at that address.

So if r9 is 0x1000, if r8 is 0x20, if r6 is 0x12345678, then 0x12345678 will be stored in memory starting at address 0x1020

```
[0x1020] = 0x78
[0x1021] = 0x56
[0x1022] = 0x34
[0x1023] = 0x12
```

Where would you use this?

```
unsigned int data[16];
...
for(ra=0;ra<16;ra++) data[ra]=ra;
```

you could for example have r9 point at data and r8 an index you can leave r9 pointing at data, then make r8 go 0x00, 0x04, 0x08 ...

```
mov r9,#0x1000
mov r8,#0x00
str r8,[r9,r8]
add r8,r8,#4
str r8,[r8,r9]
add r8,r8,#4
...
```

Notice that the order does not matter, we learned in grade school that a+b = b+a

```
STR R1, [R0]
MOV R0, #3
```

Since there is no context here.  R0 is an address (it is bits but while executing the str instruction it is an address.  The R1 bits are stored at that address.

R0 is then changed to the value 3.  And that is perfectly fine, registers are like variables, and you can reuse them for other things and that is likely what is going on here.

```
STR R6, [R9, R8]
```

R8 and R9 are valid only if the programmer makes them so.  Are you implying there is a bug here?  If so then the programmer has used the wrong values in these registers or has a bug that caused the compiler to put wrong values.  The only real wrong values you can have here is that if R9+R8 is not a word aligned address then the STR (word sized) will be an unaligned transfer, which depending on the processor and settings can cause a fault.

The stack is no different, it is in this case a known register that is used to point at the stack memory, but it is used the same way, it contains bits, during an instruction those bits are considered to be an address that point to some memory location, etc...