# Am i using the stack correctly?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am quite new to mips and was wondering if i am using the stack and understanding it correctly

So i have this block of code...

```
    la $s0, trackHeight # s0 = TH
    
    addi $sp, $sp, -4 # store TH in stack first position
    sw $s0, 0($sp)
    
    div $s0, $s0, 2 # div TH for start position (x)
    
    lw $s0, 0($sp) # restore stack
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
```

my questions are

1. when i use $s0 later, will it be the same value as before it was divided?
2. do i need to restore the stack if i will be using it later
3. when i use it later on, am i supposed to do a lw instruction to modify it

My whole project is not complete so it wont compile correctly, but i am out of t registers so i am trying to store different integers in the stack to use later on in the program.
My current understanding of the stack is minimal and i looked all over and couldnt find the answers im looking for

Comment: 1) yes  2) no 3) `lw` is a load, so it will not modify the stack. For local variables you typically allocate enough space in the function prologue then use your frame as you see fit and restore, deallocate in the epilogue.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66606426/471129

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the correct operations, in the correct order, but the comments aren't quite accurate. Here's where they should be.

```
    la $s0, trackHeight # s0 = TH
    
    addi $sp, $sp, -4 
    sw $s0, 0($sp)  # store TH in stack first position
    
    div $s0, $s0, 2 # div TH for start position (x)
    
    lw $s0, 0($sp) 
    addi $sp, $sp, 4 # restore stack
```

It's really the act of adding back the amount you subtracted that restores the stack.

As for your question about `$s0` being divided, the result of a division is actually stored in the registers `$lo` and `$hi` (one is the quotient and the other is the remainder, I forget which is which. So really, `$s0` doesn't actually change and you can omit the `lw $s0, 0($sp)` (but keep the `addi $sp, $sp, 4`, that's the important part.)

Note that this is only the case for multiplying and dividing. For other operations, if you alter an `$s_` register you will need to properly back it up and restore it, as you have done in your example.